# Python:non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

Tags: python, python-3.x

`images_name = "%s/%03d_image.jpg" % (target, i)`

I have formatted it to
`images_name = '{:03d_image.jpg}'.format((target, i))`

Could you please point me out the mistake?

Also can this be formatted in a better manner?

`format_str = ('%s: Step %d, Loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
'sec/batch)')`

`print(format_str % (datetime.now(), step, loss_value,examples_per_sec, duration))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify separate placeholders just like you've done with the old-format style and not include parts that do not need formatting within the curly braces:

```
images_name = '{}/{:03d}_image.jpg'.format(target, i)
```

The same rule applies to the second string:

```
format_str = '{}: Step {:d}, Loss = {:.2f} ({:.1f} examples/sec; {:.3f} sec/batch)'
print(format_str.format(datetime.now(), step, 
                        loss_value, examples_per_sec, duration))
```

Read more about the [old and new format specifications in Python](https://pyformat.info/).